# Read EDIT Text Files On Linux

Tags: linux, text-editors

I'm needing to read the [Adam's Assembly Tutorials](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=24671.msg181393#msg181393), that are old EDIT `*.txt` files, I'm on Linux and I need to read this files.

- What can I do?
- Is there any GUI editor that can read the files?
- There is any way to convert them into another file that is more modern<sup>1</sup>?

<sup>1</sup>: Such as *.doc, *.txt(modern ones), *.pdf, *.ps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All** editors can read plain text files. There is nothing unmodern in them. (All configuration files, all program source code, all websites, a *lot* of things are in plain text.)

If you want to see the characters as they were in DOS, use `iconv` to convert the character encoding to a "more modern" one, Unicode.

```
iconv -f cp437 -t utf-8 < file.txt > file.txt.new
```

Comment: You might also run them through `dos2unix` to convert from DOS-style to Unix-style line endings. (Read the man page first; unlike most text filters, `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` like to convert files in place.)

Answer (score 3):

There are literally dozens of programs that can read text files on Linux.  If you want to save as doc or pdf, I would suggest you use [openoffice.org](http://openoffice.org) writer.

BTW, there is nothing "unmodern" about the text files you're talking about.  The format is old but it is still in widespread use and works just fine.  It's like saying that a hammer is "unmodern" because these days nail guns exist.

Comment: But the file have a different architecture, as bullets and these things that doesn't work.

Comment: They look fine on my Linux box.  In OOo you need to select the character set "Western Europe (DOS/OS2-437 US)" when opening them. You may also need to change to a monospace font like Courier to make the layout work.